# Multithreading Multiple Functions Within A Class With Python's Threading Module

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have had success using Pythons Threading module for a single function within a class however I would like to expand it to multiple functions within a class. For example I have a program that parses some data. I have my main class and within my main class I have multiple functions that do different things with the data that is processed. Each function is called when certain conditions are met. Here is some made up program with made up functions that resembles my program.

```
class MainClass():
    def __init__(self):

        while True:
            rawData=self.receiveData(file) #a made up function to receive data
            stuffOne, stuffTwo, stuffThree, stuffFour, data=self.MainParseFunction(rawData) #returns four things and some data

            if stuffOne=="a":
                self.functionOne(data)
                print("Output of Function One")
            elif stuffTwo=="b":
                self.functionTwo(data)
                print("Output of Function Two")
            elif stuffThree=="c":
                self.functionThree(data)
                    print("Output of Function Three")
            elif stuffFour=="d":
                self.functionFour(data)
                    print("Output of Function Four")

    def MainParseFunction(self, data):
        '''Do some stuff to the data being passed to my function and return a bunch of variables to be use in the other functions '''          
    def functionOne(self, data):
        '''Do some stuff to the data being passed to my function and return a bunch of variables to be printed '''
    def functionTwo(self, data):
        '''Do some stuff to the data being passed to my function and return a bunch of variables to be printed '''
    def functionThree(self, data):
        '''Do some stuff to the data being passed to my function and return a bunch of variables to be printed '''
    def functionFour(self, data):
        '''Do some stuff to the data being passed to my function and return a bunch of variables to be printed '''

if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    MainClass()
```

While my actual program is more complex and actually processes a lot of data which I would like to use threading to speed up the process. I would like to thread one function when it is called, then another when that is called etc. Most examples I have seen only target a single function not multiple. I assume this is possible I just do not know how to go about this.

```
def threader(): 
        while True:
            job=self.q.get() 
            self.MainParseFunction(job) 
            self.q.task_done()

for _ in range(10): 
    t=threading.Thread(target=self.functionOne) 
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

for job in range(1,500): 
    self.q.put(job) 

self.q.join()
```

Comment: Isn't it enough starting one thread which each function as a target? I mean... Something like `t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.functionOne); t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.functionTwo); t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.functionThree) ... ` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to accomplish this. After reading more about the threading module I was able to code a thread that worked as I need it to without having to thread each of my functions. Here is the code from my actual program not the one above;

```
class PacketSniffer(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, rawData, currentTime):
    super(PacketSniffer,self).__init__()
    self.rawData=rawData
    self.currentTime=currentTime

    destinationMAC, sourceMAC, etherType, data = self.Ethernet_Frame(self.rawData)
    print("\t Ethernet Frame - {} - Destination: {}, Source: {}  Protocol: {}".format(self.currentTime, destinationMAC, sourceMAC, etherType))

    if etherType.__eq__(8):
        version, headerLength, TTL, protocol, source, destination, packetData=self.IPv4_Packet(data)
        print("\t IPv4 Packet - {} - Version: {}, Header Length: {}, TTL: {}, Protocol: {}, Source: {} Destination: {}".format(self.currentTime, version, headerLength, TTL, protocol, source, destination))

        if  protocol.__eq__(1):
            ICMP_type, code , checksum, packetData=self.ICMP_Packet(data)
            print("\t ICMP Packet - {} - ICMP Type: {}, Code: {}, TTL: {}, Checksum: {}".format(self.currentTime, ICMP_type, code, checksum))

        elif protocol.__eq__(6):
            sourcePort, destinationPort, seqNumber, destNumber, urgFlag, ackFlag, pshFlag, rstFlag, synFlag, finFlag, tcpData=self.TCP_Packet(data)
            print("\t TCP Packet - {} - Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}, Sequence Number: {}, Acknowledgment: {}, URG Flag: {}, ACK Flag: {}, PSH Flag: {}, RST Flag: {}, SYN Flag: {}, FIN Flag: {}".format(self.currentTime, sourcePort,destinationPort, seqNumber, destNumber, urgFlag, ackFlag, pshFlag, rstFlag, synFlag, finFlag))

        elif protocol.__eq__(17):
            sourcePort, destinationPort, datagramLength, udpData=self.UDP_Packet(data)
            print("\t UDP Packet - {} - Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}, Datagram Length: {}".format(currentTime,sourcePort, destinationPort, datagramLength))
        else:
            pass
```

Here is where I create and execute my thread.

```
if __name__.__eq__('__main__'):
try:
    connection=socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ntohs(0x0003))
except error:
    print('Connection could not be established. Program exiting!')
    sys.exit()
rawData, address = connection.recvfrom(65535)
currentTime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()))
while True:
    thread=threading.Thread(target=PacketSniffer, args=(rawData, currentTime))
    thread.daemon=True
    time.sleep(1)
    thread.start() 
thread.join()
```

I am still working on having my thread run infinitely unless I quit so for now I am using a while loop and a time.sleep() function to run my script and still be able to process the output